# How to get date on xslt file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a header path and there should be current system date along with a string.

```
<xsl:template name="GetHeaderLine">
<xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Agency</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
```

The output should be

A,Agency{CurrrentDate},

How can i fetch current date on xslt...?

Comment: Easy with XSLT 2.0, bit more involved in XSLT 1.0. Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575111/can-an-xslt-insert-the-current-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I got the answer....

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:cs="urn:cs">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="cs">
<![CDATA[
public string datenow()
{
return(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
}
]]>
</msxsl:script>
<xsl:template name="GetHeaderLine">
<xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Agency</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="cs:datenow()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

ThanQ so much for your help guys

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XPath2, use:
current-date()

but instead of this:

```
<xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Agency</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
```

I'd be tempted to use something more akin to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('A,Agency',current-date())"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
<xsl:variable name="now">
    <xsl:value-of select="document(&apos;http://xobjex.com/service/date.xsl&apos;)/date/utc/@stamp"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

And then you can use the bits you need. You can add "?offset=" to the url for different time zones.

Comment: Hi @user2532030 i tried this `<fo:block margin="10pt" font-size="10pt"><xsl:text>Today is : <xsl:variable name="now"><xsl:value-of select="document(&apos;http://xobjex.com/service/date.xsl&apos;)/date/utc/@stamp"/></xsl:variable></xsl:text>`but it is not working! anything should i do

Comment: You'll need to call the variable using <xsl:value-of select="$now"/>. like so:
<xsl:variable name="now"><xsl:value-of select="document(&apos;http://xobjex.com/service/date.xsl&apos;)/date/utc/@stamp‌​"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:text>Today is : <xsl:value-of select="$now"/></xsl:text>