# XSLT Current Date will not render

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am attempting to place the current date/time into an XSLT document.

The XSLT:

```
<xsl:template name="global" match="/">
    <body>
        <h1>Feed</h1>
        <div class="date"><xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/></div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="products[@productCode='REMSA']"/>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
```

When the current-dateTime() function is in place, it and anything below it will not render on the page. Anything above it will show up just fine. I get no errors, just blank space. This is day 4 of me looking at XSLT so I am very new this language. Any help, tips, or recommendations will go a long way.

Thank You!

Comment: When you say *will not render on the page*, do you mean that this XSLT is intended to run in a Web browser?  If so, that's your problem:  the XSLT engines built into current Web browsers support XSLT 1.0, not 2.0.  If not, tell us some more about the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed to declare the XSL function namespace to have access to the current-dateTime() function:

Add to your xsl root element the fn declaration:...:

`xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`

...and change your statement to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:current-dateTime()"/>
```

see also:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#datetime

[Can an XSLT insert the current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575111/can-an-xslt-insert-the-current-date)