# Populate current date time using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to convert XML to another XML using XSLT 2.0. Below is the code that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:eof="http://style.rbsfm.com/EnrichODCFeed" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
            xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:element name="tradeArrivalTime">
            <xsl:value-of  select="fn:current-date()"/>
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

On Testing this XSL using Junit , I am getting below Error

(Location of error unknown)javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Instance method
call to method current-date requires an Object instance as first argument

On Testing it using Eclipse XSLT complier , I am getting below Exception :

```
17:56:08,138 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Cannot find external method      
'xpath-functions.currentDate' (must be public).
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot find external method     
'xpath-functions.currentDate' (must be public).
```

Please suggest . I am not able to figure out the mistake

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575111/can-an-xslt-insert-the-current-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error suggests that the XSLT processor you're using does not support XSLT 2.0.  The default `javax.xml.transform` processor is 1.0-only, if you want to use XSLT 2.0 then you need to use a 2.0-compatible processor such as [Saxon](http://saxon.sf.net).

Saxon supports the same `javax.xml.transform` APIs so the only change you need to make to your code in order to use Saxon (once you have added the relevant JAR file or [dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sf.saxon%7CSaxon-HE%7C9.5.1-6%7Cjar) to your project) is to replace

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance()
```

with

```
new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()
```

Note that a 1.0 processor will not necessarily complain if you pass it a stylesheet that says `version="2.0"`.  Instead it will use a ["forwards-compatible" processing mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#forwards) where `xsl:` elements and functions it does not know about will not be treated as compile-time errors (only as run-time errors in cases where they are actually called).

Comment: @priyas glad it helped. When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to _accept_ the answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left. As well as rewarding the answerer (and you) with reputation points, this makes the question show up as answered in the summary lists and means other people don't waste time on it unnecessarily.