# Error on loading stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to use date and time in xsl 1.0
I tried to follow this solution: [Can an XSLT insert the current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575111/can-an-xslt-insert-the-current-date)

But I get an error saying: `Error loading stylesheet: An unknown error has occurred (805303f4)`
It does not tell me where the error is, so I'm kinda stuck.

In my xml file, here is my declaration to the namespace:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- xsl stylesheet declaration with xsl namespace:
Namespace tells the xlst processor about which element is to be processed and
which is used for output purpose only
-->
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
        extension-element-prefixes="date"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="date.xsl" />
```

And this is how I am trying to get the time and date:

`<xsl:message terminate="no"> 
    here: <xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/> 
</xsl:message>`

I downloaded the date and time package on github.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have not changed anything in the files downloaded from Github

----------------------------Update--------------
Here is the entire xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- xsl stylesheet declaration with xsl namespace:
Namespace tells the xlst processor about which element is to be processed and
which is used for output purpose only
-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
        extension-element-prefixes="date"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="date.xsl" />
  <!-- xsl template declaration:
       template tells the xlst processor about the section of xml document which is to be
       formatted. It takes an XPath expression.
       In our case, it is matching document root element and will tell processor to
       process the entire document with this template.
  -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- HTML tags
     Used for formatting purpose. Processor will skip them and browser will simply
     render them.
    -->
    <html>
      <body>
    <h2>Students</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Roll No</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Nick Name</th>
        <th>Marks</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- for-each processing instruction
           Looks for each element matching the XPAth expression
      -->
      <xsl:message terminate="no"> hello </xsl:message>
      <xsl:for-each select="class/student">
        <xsl:sort select="@rollno"/>
        <xsl:if test="marks >= 85">
          <xsl:message terminate="no"> her: <xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/> </xsl:message>
        <tr>
          <td>
        <!-- value-of processing instruction
             process the value of the element matching the XPath expression
        -->
        <xsl:value-of select="@rollno"/>
          </td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="nickname"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="marks"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the date.xsl file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/Dates and Times" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="date" date:doc="http://www.exslt.org/date">
   <import href="functions/date-time/date.date-time.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/date/date.date.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/time/date.time.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/year/date.year.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/leap-year/date.leap-year.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/month-in-year/date.month-in-year.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/month-name/date.month-name.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/month-abbreviation/date.month-abbreviation.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/week-in-year/date.week-in-year.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/day-in-year/date.day-in-year.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/day-in-month/date.day-in-month.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/day-of-week-in-month/date.day-of-week-in-month.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/day-in-week/date.day-in-week.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/day-name/date.day-name.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/day-abbreviation/date.day-abbreviation.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/hour-in-day/date.hour-in-day.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/minute-in-hour/date.minute-in-hour.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/second-in-minute/date.second-in-minute.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/format-date/date.format-date.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/parse-date/date.parse-date.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/week-in-month/date.week-in-month.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/difference/date.difference.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/add/date.add.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/add-duration/date.add-duration.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/sum/date.sum.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/seconds/date.seconds.xsl"/>
   <import href="functions/duration/date.duration.xsl"/>
</stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think you must show your complete script and the script it is importing. Otherwise your issue can’t be reproduced.

Comment: I added the entire code from the 2 files. I don't think the code from the stylesheet is important, so I did not add that

Comment: Your error specifically states “Error loading **stylesheet**”. Your stylesheet is importing many others. Have you verified their existence and validated the paths?

Comment: You are right, this was the issue

Comment: Ok. Good. If you like I can add that comment as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: Yes, do that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error specifically states:

> “Error loading *stylesheet*”.

So, your stylesheet is importing *many other* stylesheets.

What you need to do is verify their existence and validated the paths. Atleast one of them must be failing.