# Removing multiple nodes from xml

Tags: xml

I don't have any experience to create xslt transformers. please some one can help me to to transform bellow xml?

```
<Top>
   <cod>a<cod>
   <types>
       <type> 
           <start>2018-05-24</start>
           <end>2019-01-24</end>
           <empl>Ext</empl> 
       <type>
       <type> 
           <start>2019-01-25</start>
           <end>9999-12-31</end>
           <empl>Int</empl> 
       <type>  
   </types>
   <lent>10</lent> 
   <tree>asd</tree> 
</Top>
```

I need to transform it to get only latest empl type;

```
<Top>
    <cod>a<cod>
    <empl>Int</empl> 
    <lent>10</lent> 
   <tree>asd</tree> 
</Top>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that your XML is *well-formed* like this:

```
<Top>
   <cod>a</cod>
   <types>
       <type> 
           <start>2018-05-24</start>
           <end>2019-01-24</end>
           <empl>Ext</empl> 
       </type>
       <type> 
           <start>2019-01-25</start>
           <end>9999-12-31</end>
           <empl>Int</empl> 
       </type>  
   </types>
   <lent>10</lent> 
   <tree>asd</tree> 
</Top>
```

Then simply combine the *identity template* with a `copy-of` template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- Remove unnecessary space -->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />   

    <!-- identity template - copies all nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- Remove 'types' element and its children except for one 'empl' node -->
    <xsl:template match="types">
        <xsl:copy-of select="type[2]/empl" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to copy both `<empl>` elements, remove the `[2]` from the expression.

**It's output is:**

```
<Top>
    <cod>a</cod>
    <empl>Int</empl>
    <lent>10</lent>
    <tree>asd</tree>
</Top>
```

Comment: can we get the value of "empl" only if it is valued for today? (If the current date is between start and end )

Comment: You can use the XSLT-2.0 function [`current-date()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_current-date.html) or the ExSLT extension like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1575134/1305969). Using XSLT-2.0, replace the `type[2]/empl` expression with `type[substring(translate(current-date(),'-',''),1,8) > translate(start,'-','') and translate(end,'-','') > substring(translate(current-date(),'-',''),1,8)]/empl`.

Comment: This may not be the most elegant XSLT-2.0 solution, but it could also be used in an ExSLT approach.

Comment: IT is very helpful but still I have an issue with some of xml inpits. for a example if root tab contain namespace and other attributes this solution didn't work. I got some time <Top> as bellow

<Top xmlns="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:employee_interaction_send_employee_request" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: The namespace defined like this is inherited by all children. So you have to add the prefix in the XPath expressions as well. For example, add a prefixed namespace to the stylesheet element like this `xmlns:ifs="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:employee_interaction_send_employee_request"` and then change the template to `<xsl:template match="ifs:types">
        <xsl:copy-of select="ifs:type[2]/ifs:empl" />
    </xsl:template>
`.