# How can I display products in XSLT where the entry date is before today and not more than 3 days ago?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a piece of XSL code and XML as follows

This is code xml data and linked xsl correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="LaySanPhamDate.xsl"?>
<DSSanpham xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ProductXMLSchema.xsd">
    <Sanpham>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Iphone 6</name>
        <Category_id>1</Category_id>
        <description>Điện thoại iphone </description>
        <amount>100</amount>
        <price>1000000</price>
        <Created_at>2020-01-01</Created_at>
        <image type="jpg">Iphone.jpg</image>
    </Sanpham>
    <Sanpham>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Xaomi </name>
        <Category_id>2</Category_id>
        <description>Điện thoại Xaomi</description>
        <amount>200</amount>
        <price>200000</price>
        <Created_at>2020-02-02</Created_at>
        <image type="jpg">anh.jpg</image>
    </Sanpham>
    <Sanpham>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Samsung galaxy </name>
        <Category_id>3</Category_id>
        <description>Điện thoại samsung</description>
        <amount>10000</amount>
        <price>1000000</price>
        <Created_at>2020-02-02</Created_at>
        <image type="jpg">1.jpg</image>
    </Sanpham>
    <Sanpham>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>VinPro  </name>
        <Category_id>4</Category_id>
        <description>Điện thoại VinPro </description>
        <amount>1</amount>
        <price>100000000</price>
        <Created_at>2020-02-02</Created_at>
        <image type="jpg">pro.jpg</image>
    </Sanpham>
    <Sanpham>
        <id>5</id>
        <name>Oppo  </name>
        <Category_id>4</Category_id>
        <description>Điện thoại Oppo </description>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <price>1000</price>
        <Created_at>2020-02-02</Created_at>
        <image type="jpg">pro.jpg</image>
    </Sanpham>
</DSSanpham>
```

This is my xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="current-date()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Product Information</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <center>
          <h1>Display products with entry date before today and not more than 3 days ago</h1>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Product ID</th>
              <th>Product Name</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Creation Date</th>
              <th>Image</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="DSSanpham/Sanpham">
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Category_id"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="desscription"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="amount"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Created_at"/></td>
                <td><img src="{image}" alt="Product Image"/></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </center>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When there is the line <xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="current-date()"/>, the data does not display on the web browser.

And if you can, please help me solve this question.

Thank for watching

Comment: Web browsers do not support XSLT-2.0. Unfortunately :-( And `fn:current-date()`  is an XSLT-2.0 function. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1575134/1305969) seems to be an XSLT-1.0 workaround using the EXSLT package.

Comment: Note that there is a way to use XSLT 3 in the browser, the product SaxonJS from Saxonica: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml, documentation: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html